# Avoiding the focus ring in NSOutline View

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsoutlineview

I have an NSOutlineView which has contextual menu enabled for the selected row.  But, when right clicking on any other row other than the selected row, contextual menu is appearing but with a blue focus ring on the clicked row. Tried using  drawContextMenuHighlightForRow method, but with right click, even the selected row is also getting de-selected. 
How to avoid the focus ring on the clicked row(not selected row) but enable the contextual menu .

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: How does the user know which row will respond to the selected menu item?

Comment: in Validate menu item have added a condition to respond to the selectedRowIndexes.                                                                                            NSIndexSet *indexSet = [self.myView selectedRowIndexes];  Here myView is my NSOutlineView

Comment: Connect the menu to the clipview instead of the oulineview.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. Will surely try this one!!